# Is it possible ot truely reload the image?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to determine the speed of loading an image by average

My code looks something like this

```js
function test(){
    const now = performance.now();
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png"
    image.onload = function(){
        const end = performance.now(); 
        const speed = end-now
        console.log(speed)
    }
}
setInterval(test,1000)
```

The code works fine, but the problem is after the image loaded for the first time, it will loaded very first from about (64ms to less than 1 ms in my side).

My guess is the broswer will keep some data of the image until the window reloaded or closed (correct me if I am wrong)

Is it possible to prevent this without using `window.reload` and truely reload the image??

Example:

[image]

Thanks for any responds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your `now` as a query parameter to your url:

```js
function test(){
    const now = performance.now();
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1200px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png?${now}`
    image.onload = function(){
        const end = performance.now(); 
        const speed = end-now
        console.log(speed)
    }
}
setInterval(test,1000)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responds. Do you mind explain it a little bit how it work or could you provide documentations about it? Never know it before

Comment: @James, happy to elaborate. When you (GET) request an url, the response may be cached in browser. When you add query parameter(s) to the url, it's been treated as a new request (as far as the parameter(s) are differs from the previous one) thus browser cannot give you the cached response.

Comment: Wow, cool. Never know that before, another question, won't it cause by changing (adding number) after the url?

Comment: @James, cause what? =))

Comment: For example,404 error, url not founded???

Comment: @James, in your case (static content) -- no.

Comment: Thank you so much. Answer accepted. I think it works because the `?`, do you mind kindly explain a little bit or a documentation link?

Comment: @James, please [start reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL)

Comment: Thank you! I will do it